# $x\perp y$ iff $\|x+\lambda y\|\geq \|x\|$ for all scalars $\lambda$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Show that in an inner product space $X$

a) $x\perp y$ iff $\|x+\lambda y\|=\|x-\lambda y\|$ for all scalars $\lambda$

b) $x\perp y$ iff $\|x+\lambda y\|\geq \|x\|$ for all scalars $\lambda$

My Work:

I did part a). Did only the forward direction of part b). Can anybody please give me a hint for the other direction? Tried it using $\lambda=1,-1,i,-i$, but no success.

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: Here we see the difference between x\bot y and x\perp y: the first is $x\bot y$ and the second is $x\perp y$.  \perp is treated as a binary relation symbol so it provides spacing before and after; bot does not. I also changed $||x||$ to $\|x\|$.  (I don't know about the down-vote, though.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$||x+\lambda y||\geq ||x||\iff ||x+\lambda y||^2\geq ||x||^2\iff P(\lambda)= 2Re[\overline{\lambda}\langle x,y\rangle] +|\lambda|^2||y||^2\ge0$$
If $y=0$ the answer is trivial. Assume therefore $y\neq 0$. Then, if we  select
$$\lambda_0=-\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}$$
we have
$$P(\lambda_0)=-\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{\|y\|^2}$$
which is nonnegative only if $\langle x,y\rangle =0$.

Comment: Since $X$ can be complex $<x,y>^2\neq |<x,y>|^2$. Then this is not true.

Comment: I corrected it. $<y,x><x,y>=|<x,y>|^2$